# Converting Flux<Object> returned from DB to Mono<List<Dto>>

Tags: java-8, spring-webflux, project-reactor, java-9

My DB is returning Flux
I need to convert it to Mono<List> of DTO and return it to caller method. My Fruit class already has a builder method to convert Fruit to FruitDto.

If the return type of the caller method had only Mono, I could have easily mapped it as follows but since its Mono<List> I'm facing difficulty

```
 public Mono<List<FruitDto>> findAllBySearchKeys(String id){
```

//expecting to convert Flux of Fruit to Mono of List of FruitDto and return to caller

```
    return fruitRepo.findAllById(bol, status)
            .flatMap(document -> {
                return Mono.just(document.get(0).dto());
            });
```

}

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you are looking for `Flux.collectList()`

For example:

```
Flux<String> response = Flux.just("a", "b", "c");
Mono<List<String>> listMono = response.collectList();
```

Check the [documentation](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#collectList--).

Comment: I have provided the full code here, please answer the same in that question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68827253/map-directly-from-a-mono-of-list-of-objects-to-mono-of-list-of-dtos?noredirect=1#comment121646629_68827253

Comment: return fruitRepo.findAllById(bol, status).map(fruit -> fruit.dto()).collectList();