# Map directly from a mono of List of objects to mono of list of DTOs

Tags: java-8, spring-webflux, project-reactor

```
    public Mono<List<AdvancesDto>> findBySearchKeys(Map<String, String> paramsMap) {
    
        List<AdvancesDto> advDTOList= new ArrayList<>();
        return advanceRepo.findAllByKeys(
                tpNumber, vCode, arrivalNumber)
                .collectList()
                .flatMap(document -> {
                    AdvancesDto aa=document.get(0).dto();
                    advDTOList.add(aa);
                    if(document.get(1)!=null) {
                    aa = document.get(1).dto();
                    advDTOList.add(aa);
                    }
                    return Mono.just(advDTOList);
                })
                .switchIfEmpty(Mono.error(new DataException(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, "Record/s Not Found")))
                .doOnError(error -> new DataException(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, "Problem while fetching Data", error));
    }
```

DB is returning Mono of List of Advances which I'm converting into Mono of List of AdvancesDTO and returning to caller.
My Advances.java already has a builder method called dto() which converts the Advances object directly to AdvancesDTO

I want the code inside flatMap method to do direct mapping from Advances.java to AdvancesDTO.java, the current code doesn't look good and might give index out of bounds exception

Comment: `Facing issue in line 2` is not helpdul att all. Please update your question with a proper description of your problem with a proper example code that actually compiles. Voted to close.

Comment: @Toerktumlare please check now

Comment: @Toerktumlare please check now, apologies for the inconvenience

Answer (score 0):

I think you have mixed things up in your code. If you DB is returning Advances that provides a method to convert it to AdvancesDTO, change your code to:

```
public Mono<List<AdvancesDto>> findBySearchKeys(Map<String, String> paramsMap) {
    return advanceRepo.findAllByKeys(
            tpNumber, vCode, arrivalNumber)
            .map(advances -> advances.dto()) //transfer Advances to AdvancesDTO
            .collectList() //Collect them in a list.
            .switchIfEmpty(Mono.error(new DataException(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, "Record/s Not Found")))
            .doOnError(error -> new DataException(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, "Problem while fetching Data", error));
}
```

If you see your code:

```
public Mono<List<AdvancesDto>> findBySearchKeys(Map<String, String> paramsMap) {

    List<AdvancesDto> advDTOList= new ArrayList<>(); //Don't do this. collectList does this already.
    return advanceRepo.findAllByKeys(
            tpNumber, vCode, arrivalNumber)
            .collectList() //Don't collect firts, transfer the data first then collect.
            .flatMap(document -> {
                AdvancesDto aa=document.get(0).dto(); // This is also wrong, document is in reality a List<Advances>, this is not a good name at all.
                advDTOList.add(aa); 
                if(document.get(1)!=null) {  // Only the first two elements? And if there is more? 
                aa = document.get(1).dto();
                advDTOList.add(aa);
                }
                return Mono.just(advDTOList);
            })
            .switchIfEmpty(Mono.error(new DataException(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, "Record/s Not Found")))
            .doOnError(error -> new DataException(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, "Problem while fetching Data", error));
}
```

Answer (score -4):

you can use BeanUtils.copyproperties(sourceObject, targetObject)

Comment: I think you are unaware of Mono and Flux of Spring reactor webflux framework